# angular 4 : sort mat-table rxjs redux

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, angular-material

Please, I need to sort data that I load from redux store via material design table (mat-table), here is my example :

```
export class HistoryData extends DataSource<History> {

constructor(private store: Store<fromHistory.State>, private _sort: MatSort) {
    super();
}

connect(): Observable<History[]> {
    return Observable.combineLatest(
        this.store.select(fromHistory.getHistory),
        this._sort.sortChange
    ).map(([history, _]) => {
        return this.sortData(history);
    });
}

disconnect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): void {
    console.log('disc');
}

sortData(data: History[]): History[] {
        return data.sort((a, b) => {
            let propertyA: Date | string = '';
            let propertyB: Date | string = '';
            [propertyA, propertyB] = [b.updateOn, a.updateOn];

            const valueA = isNaN(+propertyA) ? propertyA : +propertyA;
            const valueB = isNaN(+propertyB) ? propertyB : +propertyB;

            return (valueA < valueB ? -1 : 1) * (this._sort.direction === 'asc' ? 1 : -1);
        });
}
}
```

My connect() method is not working, I need to listen to store and sortChange changes, can anyone help with this ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this._sort.sortChange`

Because of the way mat-table works, this observable will not generate any event until you click on one of the columns.

You can add a default initial value this way:

`merge(of({ active: 'column', direction: 'asc'}), this._sort.sortChange)`

Answer (score 0):

What output are you getting with which test data?

It looks to me like reversing `valueA < valueB` to be `valueA > valueB` makes it work.

```js
console.clear() 
const Observable = Rx.Observable

const direction = 'asc'
const sortData = (data: History[]) => {
  return data.sort((a, b) => {
    let propertyA: Date | string = '';
    let propertyB: Date | string = '';
    [propertyA, propertyB] = [b.updateOn, a.updateOn];
    const valueA = isNaN(+propertyA) ? propertyA : +propertyA;
    const valueB = isNaN(+propertyB) ? propertyB : +propertyB;
    return (valueA > valueB ? -1 : 1) * (direction === 'asc' ? 1 : -1);
  });
}

/*
  Tests
*/
// sort descending to ascending
const data1 = [
  {updateOn: new Date("2017-03-25")},
  {updateOn: new Date("2017-03-24")},
  {updateOn: ''},
  {updateOn: new Date("2017-03-23")},
]
direction = 'asc'
const result1 = sortData(data1)  //.map(x => x.updateOn.toString().substring(0,15))
console.log(result1.map(x => x.updateOn.toString().substring(0,15)))

// sort ascending to descending
const data2 = [
  {updateOn: new Date("2017-03-23")},
  {updateOn: new Date("2017-03-24")},
  {updateOn: ''},
  {updateOn: new Date("2017-03-25")},
]
direction = 'dsc'
const result2 = sortData(data2)
console.log(result2.map(x => x.updateOn.toString().substring(0,15)))

// sort jumbled to descending
const data3 = [
  {updateOn: new Date("2017-03-24")},
  {updateOn: new Date("2017-03-23")},
  {updateOn: ''},
  {updateOn: new Date("2017-03-25")},
]
direction = 'dsc'
const result2 = sortData(data2)
console.log(result2.map(x => x.updateOn.toString().substring(0,15)))
```

Runnable tests: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/gXgqKv?editors=0012)